# Count posts threads comments but also return those with no threads

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is as far as I could go:

```
SELECT link_title, count(links.unique_id) as Total 
FROM links, threads 
WHERE threads.links_id = links.unique_id 
GROUP BY links.link_title
```

This will correctly return all "links" record and corresponding comments count for each record that have threads. Problem is those links with no thread are not returned at all.

What would be the simplest way to reformat this query so it will return ALL "links" even those with 0 threads.

Comment: Show us the expected result as well. (With that input data.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an outer join (which is impossible to write with the ancient implicit join in the `where` clause you are using):

```
SELECT link_title, count(threads.links_id) as Total 
FROM links 
  LEFT JOIN threads ON threads.links_id = links.unique_id 
GROUP BY links.link_title
```

Because aggregate functions like `count()` ignore NULL values, it's important to count the number of rows in the `threads` table by using `count(threads.links_id)` as `threads.links_id` will be NULL for `links` that don't have `threads`